# Play Framework 2.5 Error with Simple Controller

Tags: scala, playframework

The error message that I get when trying out Play framework 2.5 with a simple controller is baffling. Here is what I'm doing:

```
object UserController extends Controller {

  def login = Action.async(BodyParsers.parse.json) { request =>
    val body = request.body.validate[UserLogin]
    // call the userService and validate the credentials
    body.fold(
      errors => {
        BadRequest(Json.obj("status" -> "error", "message" -> JsError.toFlatJson(errors)))
      }, // error here
      message => {
        Ok("")
      } // error here
    )
  }
}
```

I get error message that says:

```
"Expression of type Result does not conform to expected type _X"
```

Comment: I think you could remove the 'async' call or wrap the twe responses in a 'Future.successful'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to wrap the call in a Future! So here is how to do it!

```
object UserController extends Controller {

  def login = Action.async(BodyParsers.parse.json) { request =>
    val body = request.body.validate[UserLogin]
    // call the userService and validate the credentials
    body.fold(
      errors => {
        Future.successful { BadRequest(Json.obj("status" -> "error", "message" -> JsError.toFlatJson(errors))) }
      }, // error here
      message => {
        Future.successful { Ok("") }
      } // error here
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Can You expose how?